# How do I declare a member variable within the constructor that doesn't have a predefined type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to declare a member variable of a class with a type that isn't defined during compilation. I read [this article](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html) where C++17 fixed template constructors by just redacting the type paramater for a template constructor call. (I probably read it wrong because i'm getting errors.)

```
class theClass {
    template <typename UDEF> theClass(UDEF var) : memberVar(var) {}
    auto memberVar{ NULL };
};



int main() {
    int number = 3;
    theClass the(number); // Something something C++17
}
```

Does anybody have any workarounds? Maybe the `new` operator? This confuses me a lot. I'm getting super generic errors:

````
Error (active)  E0330   "theClass::theClass(UDEF var) [with UDEF=int]" (declared at line 4) is inaccessible ConsoleApplication1```
````

```
Error (active)  E1598   'auto' is not allowed here  ConsoleApplication1
```

EDIT: I tried putting the template at the initializer list as such:
 `template <typename UDEF> theClass(UDEF var) :  UDEF memberVar(var) {}`
And didn't get any IntelliSense errors, but i'm afraid it won't compile.. It's an initializer list after all, not a declaration list, right? And the odd constructor template call thingy still gives an error.

Comment: Normally, you'd do something like `UDEF memberVar;`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yeah, I tried that before.  It tells me that it's not a valid template

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1Pdf3cEY8) that uses class template argument deduction?

Comment: The error you are getting are pretty explicit IMO. `E0330` tells you the constructor you are calling is inaccessible, which is because it's private at the moment. `E1598 'auto' is not allowed here`, it is exactly what it means, you can't have a non-static member of  `auto` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template should be on the class, to have a member use the template parameter:

```
template <typename UDEF>
class theClass {
    UDEF memberVar {};
public:
    theClass(UDEF var) : memberVar(var) {}
};
```

Now your main can create an object like that:

```
int main() {
    int number = 3;
    theClass the(number); // CTAD, C++17
}
```

Comment: Hello, this worked but only after I added the template type back to the constructor call, strangely enough. Apparently the article was wrong. I edited your answer to reflect that. Thanks for helping me

Comment: @ohno Your edit is not necessary. The syntax in the paper you linked in your question and that is used in this answer (called CTAD: class template argument deduction) has been included in C++ with C++17. If you set your compiler to use C++17 or later (e.g. with the `-std=c++17` flag for GCC/Clang or the `/std:c++17` flag for MSVC), then the code will work. It seems the whole point of the question was whether such a syntax would work (i.e. without specifying the template argument list).

Comment: @user17732522 I had it on C++20 previously on the same project. (edit: the experimental one, i'm not sure if there's even a stable release of it) Very strange